# Can Threadpoolexecutor switch its blockingQueue after start?

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

Can Threadpoolexecutor change its blockingqueue after start? I am using multiple threadpoolexecutors in my process. I don't want to breach the maximum number of threads beyond a certain number in my process. That is why I thought of the idea of switching blockingqueue of my threadpool to a more busy blockingqueue. But I don't see any function in ThreadpoolExecutor class which provides the facility of switching blockingqueues. What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: "What could be the reason behind this?" It was not considered to be useful functionality at design time. I make no judgement as to whether it really is useful or not. (But presumably this functionality could be handled inside the `BlockingQueue` implementation, thus there is no need for TPE to handle it too.)

Comment: May be you need to use common pool instead of multiple theread pool executors. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--

Comment: @PratapiHemantPatel That won't be a good solution. I am working on a Monolithic architecture. Different threadpools are used to write to different resources (socket, jms and database). If I will be using same threadpool to write at all resources then may be because of db writes jms events would starve. That's not a desirable behavior because Subscribers are waiting for JMS events while no one would be waiting for db writes.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently threadpoolexecutor gives access to its blockingqueue. I can achieve the same behavior by transfering tasks from one queue to another queue.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable objects are usually favoured in modern programming practices. It usually make things... Simpler in regards to object model growth and future enhancements (And no, I don't consider python's approach of "Let's all be responsible adults" as modern for the sake of the argument).

As for solving your problem you.could perhaps pass a smart "Delegating" `BlockingQueue` implementation that'll implement the standard interface but back it with some queue switching mechanism, controlled internally or externally as your specification requires